# Possible to copy Windows 7 local user profile link with junction point to new Windows 7 machine?

Tags: windows-7, user-profiles, windows-easy-transfer

I am using Windows 7 in my old machine.  All my I user profiles store in another HDD and I use mklink/j to create a junction point to c:\users.

I bought a new machine with better performance and trying to "clone" everything from old machine to new machine.

I use clonezilla to image old machine's OS partition.  I then apply the image to new machine by using sysprep, bootrect and I able to boot up Windows 7 on new machine.  All programs and settings are there in new machine.

Next, I try to migrate the user profiles in separate HDD of old machine.  The new machine can't recognize the user profiles from old machines after I use the same method to create junction point as old machine.  When logon, I encounter "group policy client service failed to logon".

I attempt the "Windows Easy Transfer" from old machine but "Windows Easy Transfer" can't recognize the files from junction user profile".

The user profiles contains settings stores in registry and I don't want to lose it.

How may I migrate the user profile stored in junction point to new machine?

Answer (score 0):

Part of me thinks the sysprep was unnecessary and is the cause of this problem.  I haven't tested it, but I'm pretty sure that trying to reconnect the old user profile is going to cause problems.

For Windows easy transfer to work, you need to either use it before hand, or use it with the old image.  Just pointing it to the `user` folder isn't enough information.